# Redirect URL ending in -2, -3

Tags: url, redirect

How to redirect URL ending in -2 or -3 to not -2, -3

**For example:**

https://sample.com/sample-post-2 or https://sample.com/sample-post-3

**to**

https://sample.com/sample-post

Comment: I need a little more information. What web server or applications are you using? How is this website hosted?  Generally this can be achieved in the htaccess files. (mod_rewrite)

Comment: Website software is Wordpress and I'm using Plesk on Linux Server.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you do that within WordPress. https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-url-rewrite/